# Haskell's newtypes in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, haskell, types

In Haskell we can declare newtypes that allow us to hide access to the underlying data types. This allows us to create safer APIs in modules by not exposing things like the underlying array (making it impossible for the user of the library to get something out of bounds).

Is there something similar to newtypes in Typescript?

Comment: As some idea you can use this one https://github.com/gcanti/newtype-ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a follow up to this, there is another way you can introduce something similar to newtypes.

You can do the following:

```
type Seed = number & {readonly Seed: unique symbol}

const createSeed = randomNumberBetween0And1() as Seed

const doSomethingWithSeed = (s: Seed) => {...}

doSomethingWithSeed(1) // will complain
doSomethingWithSeed(createSeed()) // Will not complain
```

Comment: This looks really interesting but a bit scary - could you explain how this works? It's using some TypeScript features I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I've also read that new types done with intersection types like this can't be used for things like "keys of a map" despite being value types. Sure, you could probably make a generic wrapper around the Map type, but...

Answer (score 3):

FWIW a class with a single private field is more or less the same thing, so it’s not like a keyword is strictly *needed* for this.

Also note that the point of `newtype` in Haskell isn’t really encapsulation, although you can use it that way - it’s to enable having different types for the same structural representation, to prevent accidental misuse and to allow type based ad hoc polymorphism via type classes. Haskell’s `data` works pretty much the same way, other than implementation details the difference between `newtype A = A X` and `data A = A X` is more philosophical than technical.

Comment: Calling those "implementation details" is understating the situation.  There is a real operational difference between a pattern match on a newtype constructor and a data constructor that follows directly from the semantic differences. A case match on a newtype constructor is a no-op.  A case match on a data constructor forces evaluation, even if there's only a single constructor for the type.  This difference is huge for getting the evaluation properties correct in cases that care about them.

Comment: @Carl That's a detail relevant in some circumstances in Haskell. It's not really relevant to a discussion about how to do the same thing in Typescript.

Comment: I suppose that's the best way. Too bad that it all has to be hidden behind a class so you have to mix up modules and classes when doing functional programming in Javascript. I'd rather skip classes altogether there.

Comment: "a class with a single private field is more or less the same thing" - that's glossing over the fact that the most common use of newtypes is for numbers (e.g. for units or different ID types) and using a struct gives up value semantics and arithmetic operators which is a pretty huge disadvantage.

Comment: @Timmmm You do have value semantics if you do it right, and lack of infix operators is, at worst, a minor nuisance. Especially since in many cases (such as IDs) you'll normally not want most of them anyway.

Comment: @Timmmm, I see no evidence that the most common use of newtypes is for numbers. They're ubiquitous in monad transformers, for example, which are all over the place.